# Insert Function on Doubly Linked List

Tags: c++, pointers, doubly-linked-list

So I've got this insert function for a doubly linked list that is working for the most part just up until I try to insert a new node at a given index. I'm having trouble with linking it correctly to the nodes before and after it, if anyone could see why, I keep getting errors when I try to assign one of the points I'll point out in the code:

```
  void insert(int index, ItemType& item) 
  {

    int pos = 0;
    Node* current = new Node;
    Node* n = new Node;
    n->info = item;
    if (index >= 0 && index <= size)
    {
        if (size == 0)
        {
            head = n;
            tail = n;
            n->next = NULL;
            n->prev = NULL;
            size++;
            return;
        }
        else if (index == 0)
        {
            n->prev = NULL;
            n->next = head;
            head->prev = n;
            head = n;
            size++;
            return;
        }
        else if (index == size)
        {
            n->next = NULL;
            n->prev = tail;
            tail->next = n;
            tail = n;
            size++;
            return;
        }
        else if (index < size/2)
        {
            current = head;
            while(pos != index)
            {
            current = current->next;
            pos++;
            }

        }
        else if (index > size/2)
        {
            int endpos = size - 1;
            current = tail;
            while(endpos != index)
            {
            current = current->prev;
            endpos--;

            }
        }


    n->next = current;
    current->prev->next = n; // HERE is where the code breaks, don't know why.
    n->prev = current->prev;
    current->prev = n;
    size++;


  }
}
```

So the code breaks at the current->prev->next = n statement stating there is an access violation writing location. So I'm not sure if that is coded right or if I've messed up in pointing assignments in earlier code. If anyone knows why its doing that and can point me in the right direction that would be awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my observation,

1. Your code fails when `index = size/2`.

When there are two elements(size == 2) and when you try to insert at position 1, then `current->prev->next = n;` is meaningless

Do one of these changes `else if (index <= size/2)` or `else if (index >= size/2)`

Comment: Excellent, this was perfect, got it fixed. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If `current` is the first node in the list, then `current->prev` will be `NULL`, so `current->prev->next` will cause problems. You should check if `current` is the first item in the list before this line.

Also, your code leaks memory because you are allocating a `new Node` for `current` and you do not delete it. Since you are using `current` to move through the list rather than to create a new node, you should declare it as just

```
Node* current;
```

rather than

```
Node* current = new Node;
```